# Run Flink job on AWS EMR through Flink REST API

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, apache-flink

Apache Flink provide [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#submitting-programs) to submit its jobs. I am trying to call that REST API from my local machine but getting `java.net.UnknownHostException`. So far I successfully run my job through SSH but need to run job through REST API so that I can directly run jobs from my application/code.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace with us?

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://ip-333-33-33-33.ec2.internal
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:173)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils.getRpcUrl(AkkaRpcServiceUtils.java:138)
 ...

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node.html

Comment: Yes saw this. Its for SSH and already done. Anyways issue has been resolved as EMR was in a VPC and have some security group so I get its public IP from there to call REST service

Comment: Where did you find that internal network address and the port Flink API runs on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible via Flink REST API. The problem in my case was that my EMR IP was not public.